# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I am trying to edit the `ThemeOverlay` here which contains the dewfaults regarding the popups and dialogs and things like that but the problem is that it is not accepting the `colorBackground` attribute.

I know that some will say that I should use `android:colorBackground` but if I am inheriting from AppCompat then it should not be a problem. 
Please help.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Accent</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/TextColor</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Also, even after applying `android:colorBackground` it doesn't work. The error is gone but what I want to get done doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to :

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/TextColor</item>
</style>
```

i think you are trying to change the background, why not using an image:

```
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
```

Comment: Same thing. Error is gone but doesn't get the job done. And I wanna change background color of the Popup like on the Toolbar. If you want I can post the Toolbar code, maybe something wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

changing

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="colorBackground">@color/TextColor</item>
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/TextColor</item>
</style>
```